# Rails: param is missing or the value is empty: article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new with Rails and I began to make a web app following the rubyonrails.org tutorial.

My app is a blog with articles.. I implemented create and edit functions which worked pretty well but suddenly an error while trying to access `http://localhost:3000/articles/2/edit` in order to edit an article.
The error is `ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArticlesController#edit param is missing or the value is empty: articles`

Here is my ruby code:

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

```
def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

The line targeted by the error alert is `params.require(:articles).permit(:title, :text)`
I really don't know where the error can be because everything was ok 2 minutes ago...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Make sure you are using `:article` and not `:articles`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to update the article in the edit method. So when you navigate to "articles/2/edit/" it tries to update the article 2. But you did not pass any params.

I think what you probably want is:

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering how they had this same problem. I find that the  instructions for this are confusing in the tutorial. Since they are following the convention that the controller methods following the order of: index, show, edit, create, update, and destroy. The instructions after initially creating the 'edit' do not show the 'edit' method when creating the 'update' method but instead show the 'create' method above the 'update' method. So if you are like me and not paying careful attention you update the 'edit' method with the rest of the stuff in 'update'.

Answer (score 0):

I know is late, but i hope this solution help someone. Add to `ArticleController` these two methods:

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

and

```
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```